# How can I generate a dropdown list with PySimpleGUI, based on a list generated by a function?

Tags: python, list, user-interface, dropdown, pysimplegui

I'm using a GUI to display a dynamically generated list (will depend on the data its fed).

That list is created after clicking "Create dropdown list" and the Combo box does not give separate values of the list, instead it just joins them all as one list (and also leaves behind the placeholder I had).

Ideally, it should look like that:

[image]

But it gives me this:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def createList():
    myList = ['test', 'ok', 'friend']
    return myList

layout = [

    [sg.Button("Create dropdown list")],
    [sg.Output(key="console_output")],
    [sg.Combo(['placedholder (none)'], key='tester')],[ sg.Button("Show profile")],

]

window = sg.Window("Winner profiles", layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    if event == "Create dropdown list":
        print("Creating, please wait...")
        doneList = createList()
        print("Completed!")
        window['tester'].update(doneList)
```

I've tried things like : .update([i for i in doneList]) and the like, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I've never used `PySimpleGui`, but according to the documentation you could give `window['tester'].update(values=doneList)` a try.

Comment: Oh my. I tried something similar with the wrong prefix and thought it was wrong. This works, thanks!